# Imported data from Excel shows NA for duration greater than 24 hrs, caused by 1/1/1900 dates: how to solve?

Tags: r, excel

How to Remove 1/1/1900 dates when calculating time duration between two different days in `[h]:mm:ss` format in excel?

I am doing a guided project in which I have to perform my initial data cleaning and organizing and then import it in R for further analysis. But, the problem is that when I try to import data in R environment, the column named 'ride_length' shows NA for duration greater than 24 hrs. I think this is because excel shows `1/1/1900 6:13:00 AM`

[image]

This is because the time duration is between 2 different dates.

Due to this reason when importing data in R I'm getting `NA` in columns with values greater then 24hrs for ride_length column.

Since I wanted my time format in 37:30:35 format for duration so changing time format was not possible.
Also I tried exploring few online resources but couldn't find any solution for this.

Comment: I think it would be best if you do all cleaning in R. At least calculating the time duration should be done in R; if the start and end dates are correctly parsed then it would save you much hassle.

Comment: Please include few samples sample from your CSV file. Not as a screenshot, just open the file as a text ,copy few lines and include those in your question. If it is stored as a text, `lubridate::hms()` can parse periods that exceed 24 hours ( `lubridate::hms("98:13:00")` ) .